# hibernate reestablish connection after being lost

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I work with hibernate and oracle ,

I have this error when I didn't use my application for a period :

```
18:08:15,140 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 2396, SQLState: 61000
18:08:15,140 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time, please connect again

18:08:15,140 ERROR [STDERR] ------ Connection is closed
18:08:15,343 ERROR [JDBCTransaction] JDBC commit failed
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time, please connect again

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:283)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:278)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.receive(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:141)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:539)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:1181)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:301)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:200)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commitAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:146)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:721)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:394)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:117)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy507.getInfoEmploye(Unknown Source)
        at com.dq.admincom.web.service.BalanceService.getInfoEmploye(BalanceService.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
        at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSessionValve.handleRequest(ClusteredSessionValve.java:135)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:94)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:88)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:62)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

18:10:25,869 ERROR [JDBCTransaction] Could not toggle autocommit
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:209)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.setAutoCommit(PhysicalConnection.java:1087)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:331)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:317)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.toggleAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:228)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commitAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:173)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:146)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:721)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:394)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:117)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy507.getInfoEmploye(Unknown Source)
        at com.dq.admincom.web.service.BalanceService.getInfoEmploye(BalanceService.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
        at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSessionValve.handleRequest(ClusteredSessionValve.java:135)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:94)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:88)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:62)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
18:10:25,869 ERROR [JDBCTransaction] JDBC commit failed
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01012: not logged on

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:283)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:278)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.receive(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:141)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:539)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:1181)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:301)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:200)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commitAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:146)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:721)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:394)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:117)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy507.getInfoEmploye(Unknown Source)
        at com.dq.admincom.web.service.BalanceService.getInfoEmploye(BalanceService.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
        at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSessionValve.handleRequest(ClusteredSessionValve.java:135)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:94)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:88)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:62)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
18:10:25,869 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
18:10:25,869 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Already closed.
18:10:25,869 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
18:10:25,869 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Already closed.
```

my goal is to know how can I reestablish connection after being lost.

I added this code in _BaseRootDAO :

```
protected Session getSession(String configFile) {
        if ((null != session) && session.isOpen()) {
            return session;
        } else if (null != sessionFactory) {
            Session s = currentSession.get();

            if ((null == s) || !s.isOpen()) {
                s = sessionFactory.openSession();
                currentSession.set(s);
            } else {
                try {
                    HibernateWork hibernateWork = new HibernateWork("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
                    s.doWork(hibernateWork);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("------ Connection is closed");

                    s = sessionFactory.openSession();
                    currentSession.set(s);
                }
            }

            return s;
        } else {
            Session s = currentSession.get();

            if ((null == s) || !s.isOpen()) {
                s = getSessionFactory(configFile).openSession();
                currentSession.set(s);
            }

            return s;
        }
    }
```

and I make this config in applicationContext-db.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>


      <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.22:1521:testSid"/>
        <property name="username" value="testUser"/>  
        <property name="password" value="testUser"/>
         <property name="maxActive" value="1500"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="1000"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="20000"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="3600"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: i think you should not get such an exception. Oracle database might return about 20 error codes with meainig connection is lost or database is not available. In JBoss source codes there is a class called OracleExceptionSorter which should handle this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look good what you do in getSession() method.
Mainly because you should not deal with connection at this level.

It is the Datasource and the connection pool that should manage the connections.
The answer to your problem must be in the datasource configurations.

[Here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) is the documentation for the datasource you use.
My guess is you should play with `validationQuery` and `testOnBorrow`

Try something like this (also take some time to understand the parameters to datasource from the link):

```
<beans>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>


      <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.22:1521:testSid"/>
        <property name="username" value="testUser"/>  
        <property name="password" value="testUser"/>
         <property name="maxActive" value="1500"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="1000"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="20000"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="3600"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I work with jboss 5,  I think that I should add a test of reconnect in jboss , like this <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>,   but I didn't find which file in jboss should be configured,